# Find multiple blank lines in Notepad++ and join the separated text lines

Tags: notepad++, macros, join

How to find multiple blank lines in Notepad++ and join the the separated text lines with a macro?

Below is screenshot of the file, where I want a macro to find out this blank line and correct the SEE and FIGURE should come to one line.

[image: picture of the file]

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R{2,}`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R{2,}  : 2 or more any kind of linebreak, '\r' or '\n' or '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what's actually on those lines it might already be sufficient to just Search & Replace `\r\n\r\n` in extended mode with nothing or maybe a space. If you do have more whitespace characters you could use a regular expression.